# How to use count method to show how many records are in the db

Tags: python, django

I have a question with count() method. I have the class Kategorie in my models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone


class Kategorie(models.Model):
    glowna = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name='Kategoria')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name='Kategoria'
        verbose_name_plural='Kategorie'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.glowna


class Witryna(models.Model):
    nazwa = models.CharField(default="", max_length=150, verbose_name = 'Nazwa strony')
    adres_www = models.CharField(max_length=70, verbose_name='Adres www')
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, verbose_name='Przyjazny adres url')
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Adres e-mail')
    text = models.TextField(max_length=3000, verbose_name='Opis strony')
    kategoria = models.ForeignKey(Kategorie, verbose_name='Kategoria')
    data_publikacji = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Data publikacji')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name='Strona www'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Strony www'

    def publikacja(self):
        self.data_publikacji=timezone.now()
        self.save()


    def __str__(self):
        return self.nazwa
```

And I made definition in views.py

```
def widok_kategorii(request):
    kategorie = Kategorie.objects.all()
    wpisy_kat = Kategorie.objects.count()
    return render(request, 'firmy/widok_kategorii.html', {'kategorie': kategorie, 'wpisy_kat': wpisy_kat})
```

the view in html file showing me the number of all Kategories but I want to have a result for example how many websites are in the for example category Business? I have to use count() with some arguments it filters?

Comment: `Witryna.objects.filter(kategorie=x).count()`

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but just a remark. It is a good practice to use singular for the class names in your models.py. So **Kategoria** would be better than **Kategorie**. You have **Wytrina** also in singular.

Answer (score 1):

You may try:

```
e_comm_count = Witryna.objects.filter(kategoria__glowna='Business').count()
#                                             Your value here^^^^
```

For count witryna for each category you may use [annotate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/aggregation/#cheat-sheet), it looks like:

```
from django.db.models import Count

    wpisy_kat = Kategorie.objects.annotate(cnt_witryna=Count('Witryna'))
```

in the queryset you may find new attr `cnt_witryna`, hope it help.

Comment: Ok I understand what You mean but I have now 56 records added in class Kategorie

Comment: do you want list of categories with counts of Witryna instance for each category?

Comment: @killerbees add new to the answer

Comment: I will try this solution when I come back to house. When I use annotate after in html file I have to use {% wpisy_kat %} only to show the result of query?

Comment: No `{% wpisy_kat %} `  something like `{% for k in wpisy_kat %}`

Comment: Ok thank You very much. I'll try it later nad if will be some problem I'll let You know

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know how many `Witryna` are in the category `Business` you can do:

```
Witryna.objects.filter(kategoria__glowna="Business").count()
```